# Terminal acts like package still exists after uninstalling

Tags: package, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I am troubleshooting and issue by attempting to uninstall and reinstall  `zathura` and `zathura-pdf-poppler`.  After uninstalling:

```
sudo pacman -Rcns zathura
sudo pacman -Rcns zathura-pdf-poppler
```

My terminal still behaves like `zathura` still exists.

```
$ zathura --version
zathura: error while loading shared libraries: libgirara-gtk3.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume this is because I broke my packages somehow (maybe with `yay`) at some point when attempting to fix the zathura package.

When `zathura` and `zathura-pdf-poppler` are installed with `pacman` attempting to run `zathura` gives the error

```
error: Found no plugins. Please install at least one plugin.
```

Despite the fact that the plugins are installed in the correct directory:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/zathura; ls
libpdf-poppler.so  pdf.so
```

But I don't know if this information is relevant or not.

This is all on Manjaro 23.0.4 with zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue, zathura can be fully deleted by looking at where it is still located in your $PATH after you deleted it using pacman, for me this was in /usr/bin, I think this might be due to an update that they moved the execution file without removing the old one. I still have the issue with libgirara-gtk3.so.3 after reinstalling and it's because it doesn't exist anymore, it's now libgirara-gtk3.so.4 ... So I'm guessing they updated girara whilst zathura is not jet updated in the arch linux repository, so I managed to get it to work by building from source.

Comment: I manually uninstalled some files in `/usr/bin` and then completely reinstalled and eventually got it to work.